# Databases (RDBMS, NoSQL) difficulty with terminology

Tags: sql, database, rdbms, nosql

I have some difficulty in understanding the terminology of NoSQL, RDBMS (where they belong, category etc).

From my understanding, you have a 'Database Management System', which has many types such as the relational and ER model.
A RDBMS is based on the relational model.

Now you have NoSQL, which is a type of Database management system, which also has many types (key/value, document store etc.)

So basically, a DBMS and NoSQL are, term wise, on the same level but have different data models? 
Am I correct?

Comment: HI JustLearning; I'm afraid this is a bit off topic for a programming stackExchange site. Have you read the wikipedia articles?

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry for that. I did, but I still don't quite get a good picture of it yet. I have Googled the terms DBMS, RDBMS, NoSQL but really couldn't understand which can be compared, which belongs where.

Comment: Yeah, really, try wikipedia. It explains everything quite well.

Answer (score 0):

The [Wikipedia article on NoSQL is very appropriate, please read it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL).

The short answer is that a relational database management system is any system that manages data by...relations.   NoSQL is far less descriptive.  It's a host of very different approaches for managing data.  They really don't have much in common with one another other than that they're not RDBMS.  To further confuse things, NoSQL may actually *use* SQL, hence why people now call it "Not Only SQL" instead of actually "No SQL".